# iPad 2 , iPod FaceTime

Tags: facetime

I just bought an iPad 2. My daughter has an iPod. We set up her iPod for FaceTime. How can I set up FaceTime on my iPad using a different email address. I don't want both devices to ring. Is this possible.

Answer (score 3):

Create an Apple ID for yourself and use that for FaceTime on your iPad. It works best if you have a separate Apple ID for yourself in other ways as well.